# flutter: CircleAvatar with fallback text

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm learning Flutter and would like to make a `Widget` just like the built-in `CircleAvatar`.  However, I would like the behaviour to be

- specify both an Image (`NetworkImage`) and initials (ie, BB)
- while the image isn't loaded, show the initials
- if the image does load, show the image and remove the initials

The following code sort of works, but when used in the Chat demo it falls apart as multiple MyAvatars are added.
Breakpointing on initState shows that it is always called with the first message text that is entered - not what I expected.
It also flickers as images "reload".  It appears that the widgets are being reused in a way I don't understand.

```
class MyAvatar extends StatefulWidget {                     
  NetworkImage image;
  MyAvatar({this.text}) {
    debugPrint("MyAvatar " + this.text);
    if (text.contains('fun')) {
      this.image = new NetworkImage("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/minicons-for-web-sites/24/minicons2-14-512.png");
    }
  }
  final String text;
  @override                                                        
  MyAvatarState createState() {
    return new MyAvatarState();
  }                    
}

class MyAvatarState extends State<MyAvatar> {
  bool showImage = false;
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.image != null) {
      var completer = widget.image.load(widget.image);
      completer.addListener((info, sync) {
        setState(() {
          showImage = true;
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return !showImage ? new CircleAvatar(radius: 40.0, child: new Text(widget.text[0]))
        : new CircleAvatar(radius: 40.0, backgroundImage: widget.image);
  }
}
```

I'm still having trouble - full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Modify the ChatScreen class definition to extend StatefulWidget.

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {                     //modified
  ChatScreen() {
    debugPrint("ChatScreen - called on hot reload");
  }
  @override                                                        //new
  State createState() {
    debugPrint("NOT on hot reload");
    return new ChatScreenState();
  }                    //new
}

// Add the ChatScreenState class definition in main.dart.

class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final List<ChatMessage> _messages = <ChatMessage>[];
  final TextEditingController _textController = new TextEditingController(); //new
  ChatScreenState() {
    debugPrint("ChatScreenState - not called on hot reload");
  }

  @override //new
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Friendlychat")),
      body: new Column(                                        //modified
          children: <Widget>[                                         //new
            new Flexible(                                               //new
                child: new ListView.builder(                              //new
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),                       //new
                  reverse: true,                                          //new
                  itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],        //new
                  itemCount: _messages.length,                            //new
                )                                                         //new
            ),                                                          //new
            new Divider(height: 1.0),                                   //new
            new Container(                                              //new
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),                   //new
              child: _buildTextComposer(),                         //modified
            ),                                                          //new
          ]                                                            //new
      ),                                                             //new
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextComposer() {

    return new IconTheme(
        data: new IconThemeData(color: Theme
            .of(context)
            .accentColor),
        child:
        new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container( //new
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0), //new
                    child: new IconButton( //new
                        icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
                        onPressed: () =>
                            _handleSubmitted(_textController.text)), //new
                  ),
                  new Flexible(
                      child: new TextField(
                        controller: _textController,
                        onSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                            hintText: "Send a message"),
                      )
                  ),
                ])
        )
    );
  }

  void _handleSubmitted(String text) {


    _textController.clear();
    ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(text: text);
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
  }
}

const String _name = "Hardcoded Name";

class ChatMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  ChatMessage({this.text, this.image, this.useImage});
  final String text;
  final NetworkImage image;
  final Map useImage;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var use = true; //useImage != null && useImage['use'];

    var image = new NetworkImage("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/minicons-for-web-sites/24/minicons2-14-512.png");
    if (text.contains('bad')) {
      image = new NetworkImage("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/minicons-for-web-sites/24/minicons2-14-512.pngz");
    }
    return new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
      child: new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
            child : new CustomCircleAvatar(initials: text[0], myImage: image)
          ),
          new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(_name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
              new Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                child: new Text(text),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomCircleAvatar extends StatefulWidget {
  NetworkImage myImage;

  String initials;


  CustomCircleAvatar({this.myImage, this.initials}) {
    debugPrint(initials);
  }

  @override
  _CustomCircleAvatarState createState() => new _CustomCircleAvatarState();
}

class _CustomCircleAvatarState extends State<CustomCircleAvatar>{

  bool _checkLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.myImage != null) {
      widget.myImage.resolve(new ImageConfiguration()).addListener((image, sync) {
        if (mounted && image != null) {
          setState(() {
            _checkLoading = false;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _checkLoading == true ? new CircleAvatar(child: new Text(widget.initials))
        : new CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: widget.myImage);
  }
}
```

Enter 'fun' as a message, then 'bad' as the second - 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Oj6.png)
The idea is that depending on what you enter, different images might load (or not).  In the 'failed to load' case, the initials should remain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality by adding a listener to `ImageStream` that you can obtain from `ImageConfiguration`,

Here, I am feeding the same data to my `ListView` you can of course customize this yourself by adding a `List` of images and initials as a field in any class and use `ListView.builder` instead to be able to loop on them by index.

[image]

```
class CustomCircleAvatar extends StatefulWidget {
  NetworkImage myImage;

  String initials;


  CustomCircleAvatar({this.myImage, this.initials});

  @override
  _CustomCircleAvatarState createState() => new _CustomCircleAvatarState();
}

class _CustomCircleAvatarState extends State<CustomCircleAvatar>{

  bool _checkLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.myImage.resolve(new ImageConfiguration()).addListener((_, __) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _checkLoading = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _checkLoading == true ? new CircleAvatar(
        child: new Text(widget.initials)) : new CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: widget.myImage,);
  }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp (home: new MyApp()));
}

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Custom Circle Avatar"),),
          body: new ListView(children: new List.generate(20, (int index) {
            return new Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              child: new CustomCircleAvatar(myImage: new NetworkImage(
                  "https://www.doginni.cz/front_path/images/dog_circle.png"),
                initials: "Dog",
              ),
            );
          }),),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: That's excellent - thank you very much, it worked perfectly.  Now to understand why :)

Comment: @bradbeveridge I am glad it helped, you can give me something to be able to reproduce the error you are getting

Comment: I'm afraid I was wrong, I'm still not quite able to get what I'm trying to do :)  I've updated the original question.  Thanks very much for your time & help.

Comment: Why do you need to check if text contains "bad" ? I am not sure I understand your purpose here.

Comment: Let's say the chat application will display an avatar for each person in a group chat.  If that person's avatar is blank or doesn't load, show their initials.  The check for 'bad' is just to emulate that a message came from somebody with an avatar that won't load.  In the latest code I posted, the 'bad' messages show no image and no initials.

Comment: I see what you are doing, but I think there is something not accurate about mimic-ing the "image not loaded" behavior the way you did it. You should just test the code one time with a valid linked, and another time with an invalid link and see what you get? because after all this is how it work.

Comment: The reason I said this is because user avatar is obtained from backend anyway, whether it is uploaded to your app database, or obtained from google or facebook, so you need to handle exceptions of not being connected to the internet or uploading an invalid image in the first place.

Comment: Furthermore, the way you are checking using "bad" text, is not proper, there is something related to the text itself that prevents it from handling the logic, I can not yet figure it out, so just try to feed a valid image url one time, and an invalid one another time and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks very much for your efforts.  Since I'm only learning at this stage, I think I'll put this particular puzzle down and move on to trying to build a real app.

Answer (score 3):

This works really well and easy. Use the `CachetNetworkImage` and build the appropriate `CircleAvatar`.

```
return CachedNetworkImage(
      httpHeaders: headers,
      imageUrl: general.HOST + 'api/media/v2/' + id,
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>  new CircleAvatar(
        radius: radius,
          backgroundImage: imageProvider,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          radius: radius,
          child: new Text(initials, style: textStyle,)),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @aziza was really the only one I could find on the topic for a while and it took me a while to read it and understand. I tried implementing it and there were some issues though I did get it to work eventually. I think I have a more readable (for me at least!)/up to date answer that might help someone stumbling upon this question:

```
class FallBackAvatar extends StatefulWidget {
  final AssetImage image;
  final String initials;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final Color circleBackground;

  FallBackAvatar({@required this.image, @required this.initials, @required this.circleBackground, @required this.textStyle});

  @override
  _FallBackAvatarState createState() => _FallBackAvatarState();
}

class _FallBackAvatarState extends State<FallBackAvatar> {

  bool _checkLoading = true;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Add listeners to this class
    ImageStreamListener listener = ImageStreamListener(_setImage, onError: _setError);

    widget.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(listener);
  }

  void _setImage(ImageInfo image, bool sync) {
    setState(() => _checkLoading = false);
    //DO NOT DISPOSE IF IT WILL REBUILD (e.g. Sliver/Builder ListView)
    dispose();
  }

  void _setError(dynamic dyn, StackTrace st) {
    setState(() => _checkLoading = true);
    dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _checkLoading == true ? new CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: widget.circleBackground,
        child: new Text(widget.initials, style: widget.textStyle)) : new CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: widget.image,
      backgroundColor: widget.circleBackground,);
  }
}
```

A couple of points, I'm manually disposing because I know after this there should be no more rebuilds (did you get the image? good! no more rebuilds unless you are part of a sliver or something OR did the image fail to load? well that's it then - no more rebuilds). This also handles the error case where the AssetImage (in my case, its Asset image but you could use any kind of image provider) is not there for whatever reason.

**Second edit,** because I have personal problems best left out of this answer. So I noticed that there was a slight delay in loading the profile images (like a second). But then the images came flooding in. Didn't like that transition so here is one with an AnimatedSwitcher:

```
class FallBackAvatar extends StatefulWidget {
  final AssetImage image;
  final String initials;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final Color circleBackground;
  final double radius;
  final int msAnimationDuration;

  FallBackAvatar({@required this.image, @required this.initials, @required this.circleBackground, @required this.textStyle, @required this.radius, this.msAnimationDuration});

  @override
  _FallBackAvatarState createState() => _FallBackAvatarState();
}

class _FallBackAvatarState extends State<FallBackAvatar> {

  bool _imgSuccess = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Add listeners to this class
    ImageStreamListener listener = ImageStreamListener(_setImage, onError: _setError);

    widget.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(listener);
  }

  void _setImage(ImageInfo image, bool sync) {
    setState(() => _imgSuccess = true);
  }

  void _setError(dynamic dyn, StackTrace st) {
    setState(() => _imgSuccess = false);
    dispose();
  }

  Widget _fallBackAvatar() {
    return Container(
      height: widget.radius*2,
      width: widget.radius*2,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: widget.circleBackground,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(widget.radius))
      ),
      child: Center(child: Text(widget.initials, style: widget.textStyle))
    );
  }


  Widget _avatarImage() {
    return CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: widget.image,
      backgroundColor: widget.circleBackground
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.msAnimationDuration ?? 500),
      child: _imgSuccess ? _avatarImage() : _fallBackAvatar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the code can be even simpler:

if you want to put a text when the image is unavailable you should simply use foregroundImage instead of backgroundImage.

The text will displayed by default, when the image is loaded it will cover the text without having to deal with image loading status etc.

If you need to know if the image had an error you can intercept it with onForegroundImageError.

Example function:

```
Widget CircleAvatarTest(
    {String? imageUrl,
    String? text,
    double radius = 35,
    Color? backgroundColor}) {
  return CircleAvatar(
    radius: radius,
    child: (text != null)
        ? Center(
            child: Text(text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: radius * 2 / text.length - 10,
                )),
          )
        : null,
    foregroundImage: imageUrl == null ? null : NetworkImage(imageUrl),
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    //onForegroundImageError: (e,trace){/*....*/},
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample with stacked architecture where fallback is person icon.
`ViewBuilder` and `ViewModel` are just extended widgets from stacked architecture alternatives. `@swidget` is functional widget. You can achieve the same functionality via `StatefulWidget`.

```
@swidget
Widget avatarView({String userId, double radius = 24}) =>
    ViewBuilder<AvatarViewModel>(
      viewModelBuilder: () => AvatarViewModel(),
      builder: (model) => CircleAvatar(
        radius: radius,
        backgroundColor: CColors.blackThird,
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
          Config.photoUrl + userId ?? userService.id,
        ),
        child: model.isFailed ? Icon(EvaIcons.person, size: radius) : null,
        onBackgroundImageError: (e, _) => model.isFailed = e != null,
      ),
    );

class AvatarViewModel extends ViewModel {
  bool _isFailed = false;

  bool get isFailed => _isFailed;

  set isFailed(bool isFailed) {
    _isFailed = isFailed;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```