# How to add labels to circle avatar in flutter

Tags: flutter, label, title, avatar

I have created a circle avatar and want to show the label for it as to make it clear for what the avatar is.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [circular_profile_avatar package](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_profile_avatar), you cant add `label` or `title` to `CircleAvatar`. by this package you can add `Text` over your like `Stack`.

if you didnt like package you can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809189/flutter-circleavatar-with-fallback-text), i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Stack** widget sample usage:

```html
Stack(
alignment: Alignment.center
  children: <Widget>[
    CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: ClipRect(
          child: Image.network(
            'url-to-image',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      )
     Center(
     child: Text(
     'label',
     textAlign: TextAlign.center))
  ],
```